# How to Show Property value in Error Message

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-web-api, data-annotations, model-validation

I'm using Model validation to show the error message. like below

```
    public class ClientData
{

    [DataMember]
    [MaxLength(10, ErrorMessage = "ERR-ClientSequenceId-02:Enter maximum of 10 characters")]
    public string CSeqId { get; set; }


    [DataMember]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "ERR-Number-01:Number is required")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\d{9}$", ErrorMessage = "ERR-Number-02:Enter Valid Number")]
    [MaxLength(9, ErrorMessage = "ERR-Number-03:Maximum 9 digits only allowed")]
    [SampleText("003333330")]
    public string ClientNumber { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [MaxLength(2, ErrorMessage = "ERR-STATE-04:State code in 2 characters for the Client Data Address")]
    [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z{2}]+$", ErrorMessage = "ERR-STATE-05:Enter a valid Client Data Address State code")]
    [SampleText("AL")]
    public string StateCd { get; set; }
}
```

Here the error message shows from **ErrorMessage**.

But I want to add the **CSeqId** value to all the ErrorMessage like "123 ERR-Number-01: Number is required". here 123 is CSeqId value.

How can I do using model validation? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can include this in your view: `@Html.ValidationMessage("Id")`

And in your controller, check if the value is null, and if it is, create a custom model error like so:

`ModelState.AddModelError("Id", id + " ERR-Number-01: Number is required")`

The error message will display just like any model state validation error.

Comment: It's not MVC Model. It is DataContract Model.